# Selenium InternetExplorerDriver Does Not Wait Till Page Loads

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I faced problem with InternetExplorer WebDriver that drives me crazy.

IE for some reason doesn't wait till page is loaded and continue execute code.

The following code opens Google page and doesn't open Wikipedia page just after:

```
var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://wikipedia.org");
```

There is an completely different behavior in FireFox. This code opens Google page and then opens Wikipedia page:

```
var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://wikipedia.org");
```

How I can get IE behaves same as FireFox?

IE Version - 11.0.9600.17107; Selenium.WebDriver Version - 2.42 (NuGet installation); 
Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver Version - 2.24 (NuGet installation)

Here is code that I used to test with Explicit Waits. As result of this test I get "OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: Timed out after 30 seconds ---> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to find element on closed window":

```
[TestMethod]
public void Open()
{
    var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://wikipedia.org");

    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    var myElement = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input#www-wikipedia-org")));
    Assert.IsNotNull(myElement);
}
```

Just checked suggestion with setting page load timeout. Didn't help. Behavior is the same.

Best regards,

Dmitry

Comment: I work with selenium and Java. Try putting a Thread.sleep() after first goToUrl()

Comment: It's worth noting that the IEDriverServer you're using is very old if it's 2.24. There is no official NuGet package maintained by the Selenium peoject for the IE driver executable; packages containing compiled binaries are frowned upon in the NuGet ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

I use Windows 7/IE 11 and a test sequence moved from Windows 7/IE 10 started suddendly to not wait for page load; after 10 msec it went ahead to the next page and so on.

I "fixed" the issue setting Protected Mode to off in all four areas (Internet, Local internet, Trusted sites and Restricted sites) into Internet options dialog; it is mandatory to switch off the flag everywhere because otherwise IEWebDriver complains about it and does not start IE at all. It fixed also the problem that sometimes the IE window remained open at the end of the test despite of the explicit command to close it.

It leaves room open to malicious attacks so it is not for all cases, but works.

Comment: I would just like to point out that it is **not** mandatory to disable Protected Mode in all zones. It's perfectly acceptable to enable it for all zones too, which preserves the security for which Protected Mode was designed. [This blog post](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html) describes the technical reasons why Protected Mode settings must be set in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a print statement in-between! I don't know why it works (and why not without), but it works on my PC. With Java and TestNG, the code would look as below:

```
@BeforeTest
public void setup() {   
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:/Dependancies/IEDriverServer.exe");
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
}

@Test
public void test() {
    driver.get("http://www.gamedev.net/page/index.html");
    //System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    System.out.println("Hello");
    driver.get("http://www.gamasutra.com/");
}
```

Note that:

1. I have declared a driver variable of type WebDriver at class-level (instance variable).
2. I made sure that I am using 64-bit version of Internet Explorer driver as I am using 64-bit version of Internet Explorer browser. If you are using 32-bit version of Internet Explorer browser, you will need to use 32-bit version of Internet Explorer driver. How to find which version of Internet Explorer browser we are using: By checking path of it's executable file, whether it is in "Program Files" or in "Program Files (x86)".
3. If you are using C#, you can put a Console.WriteLine() statement instead of System.out.println() statement.

Answer (score 0):

Add an [implicit wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) to your code, after the initial web driver initialization. This will allow the initial page to completely load, before the next step is taken.

Comment: Implicit wait does not help. IE is not waiting for page loaded at all.
I tried this code and Wikipedia is not loaded:
var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://wikipedia.org");

Comment: Use an Explicit Wait instead, choose an element on the wikipedia page, and wait explicitly for that element before continuing.

Comment: Just tried with explicit wait.
Got this exception: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: Timed out after 30 seconds ---> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to find element on closed window.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code(C#):

```
Driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
```

The above code will wait up to 10 seconds for page loading. If the page loading exceeds the time it will throw the TimeoutException. This is an implicit wait. If you set this once it will have the scope until the Web Driver instance destroy.

Comment: Just checked that. Didn't help. Behavior is the same. Code:
var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://wikipedia.org");

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply ad a:

```
driver.findElement(By.by("element_to_wait_for"));
```

It will look for an element that you know that exits in the page till it runs out of time.

You will probably also have to change the timeout for it not to fail right away.